# Why doesn't my bash include the interactive flag for this script?

Tags: bash, interactive

Working with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46801/79839) I have tried this script to determine whether a script is being run from `cron` or interactively:

```
#!/bin/bash

# "reliable" interactive check
case "$-" in
        *i*)
                interactive=1
                ;;
        *)
                interactive=0
                ;;
esac

echo \$-=$- interactive=$interactive 

# "maybe" interactive check
if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
        interactive=1
else
        interactive=0
fi

echo interactive=$interactive
```

Shockingly I get conflicting answers for whether it is interactive or not.  Here is the output when I run it from the bash prompt:

```
$-=hB interactive=0
interactive=1
```

And FYI I'm on Mint 18 with:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redist
```

So my core question is why does the "reliable" method produce the wrong answer?  Why hasn't bash included the expected flag in the options?  [The docs](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f) seem to indicate that it should.  Is the "maybe" works version actually more reliable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “reliable” method fails because “this shell” is the shell running the script, which isn’t interactive, not the shell you started the script from.

Checking whether standard input is a terminal (`[[ -t 0 ]]`) is somewhat more reliable, but it still isn’t determining whether the script is running from `cron`: there are ways to run a script in such a way that `[[ -t 0 ]]` succeeds, even when it’s not running from a terminal.

The accepted answer to [Check if script is started by cron, rather than invoked manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46789/86440) seems more reliable to me.

Answer (score 0):

`[[ -t 0 ]]` just determines whether fd0 is open on a (pseudo)terminal.  Since fd0 is standard input, it typically is.