# detecting cli script execution and not cronjob script execution

Tags: shell-script, cron, console

Is there a way to detect if i run a shell script by hand in the console or if the cron starts the script (e.g. using crontab) ?

Edit: 
Usage example: manualy i want to show a progress bar for example which cron should not show.

Comment: You can detect if you are attached to a tty. What is the reason that you need to know, if may affect the answer?

Comment: manual: show a progress bar, else not, for example :) but how to detect that tty which runs the script

Comment: According to Unix philosophy. A program should only output, what it is asked to output. Therefore add an option e.g. `--show-progress`, so that a user can ask for it. Doing otherwise can annoy users, of your program.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thx! Good point!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you actually want to detect whether or not a terminal (TTY) is available to the application. (This will allow you to display a progress bar when running on a terminal, but not bother if running under `crontab`.)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
[[ -t 2 ]] && echo "This is a status update for the terminal" >&2
echo "This is a normal line of results"
```

The `test -t` operation checks to see whether or not the numbered file descriptor is connected to a terminal. 0 is *stdin*, 1 is *stdout*, and 2 is *stderr*.

Generally, progress information would be written to *stderr* with actual results written to *stdout*. This way the user can discard progress/status output if they don't want to see it, and status updates and results can be separated usefully:

```
yourprogram arg1 arg2 ... > results.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! i just found this simmilar post [1] where $TERM could be also an option to detect it? test -t  = $TERM ?
[1]: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46789/check-if-script-is-started-by-cron-rather-than-invoked-manually

Comment: @fb not really. I could set `TERM` in `crontab` or unset it on a terminal. I can't set the `-t` test.